# Jlist not adding selected item

Tags: swing, netbeans, jlist, jtree

List declarations

```
private javax.swing.JTree SourcebooksAvailablePanel;
private javax.swing.JList<String> sourcebooksSelectedPanel;
```

So the JTree has stuff in it that I want to selectively copy over the JList (created in NetBeans GUI builder). Basically select the bit you want, hit the button and it copies over to the list.

Here is the code so far for the transfer: So far everything works but the last line seems to be ineffective. It compiles fine.

```
private void bookAddButtonMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
String bookName = SourcebooksAvailablePanel.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString();
// temp variable to grab the contents of selected Jtree node and put into string
JLabel bookLabel = new JLabel(bookName);
//temp invisible label to put into Jlist because Jlist add method doesn't like Strings. Takes bookName as its text

//add code to check if user has already added item at later point

Object balls = SourcebooksAvailablePanel.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
System.out.println(balls); //temp to check if the balls work

int index = sourcebooksSelectedPanel.getLastVisibleIndex(); //get last index of list
if (index == -1) //no items currently populating list
{
    index = 0; //lists and arrays are 0 indexed in Java so this puts the item at the beginning
}
else
{
    index++; //add after the current last item in list
}

Component add = sourcebooksSelectedPanel.add(bookLabel, index);
//supposed to add bookLabel's text to the specified index of the list but nope.
//everything else has been tested and works. Just this command
```

If I change bookLabel to balls in the last line it throws up an error "suitable method not found".

OK where am I going wrong with this? Please don't tell me to refer to Oracle's documentation because I went there already and it's how I got the majority of this code in the first place apart from replacing addElement() with add().

Answer (score 2):

> Please don't tell me to refer to Oracle's documentation

Actually that is exactly what you need to do. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

If you look at the working example code from the `ListDemo` example you will see that you add the data to the `DefaultListModel` NOT the `JList`.

Also, you will see that you add the `String` to the `DefaultListModel`, NOT a `JLabel`.

So, yes, the working example from the tutorial is the place to start. Learn from working examples. The code you posted looks nothing like the working example.

Also you would use `getSelectedIndex()`, NOT getLastVisibleIndex() to determine where to insert the data. You will then need to read the `DefaultListModel` API for the method to insert the data at a specific location in the model.

Comment: Just for the first paragraph alone +1

Comment: I've read the documentation, that is how I got most of the code. When I tried putting the bookName string into the add() method it threw up an error "no suitable method found" no matter whether the order was index, bookName or bookName, index.<br>

So what you're saying is that JList is just a container that I stick another list into?

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm actually not a programmer by trade and kinda flying by the seat of my arse here.

Comment: @Carrie Please mind your language on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `I tried putting the bookName string into the add() method it threw up an error "no suitable method found"` - and why did you try doing that??? The example code does not do that, so why are you making up code?. `So what you're saying is...` - hat is not what I am saying. I am saying you have a working example that shows how to add text to a JList, so learn from the working example.  `flying by the seat of my arse` - that is my point. Follow the example and you won't have a problem. Don't make up code.

Comment: Why would I need to do the list creation when the list has already been created by the NetBeans GUI builder?

Comment: @Carrie, No idea what you are talking about. Your question is about adding an item to the Jlist when the user makes a selection. The tutorial shows you exactly how to add a String to the JList via the DefaultListModel. If you have a question about the code from the tutorial then ask it. The IDE is completely irrelevant for this question.